# Analytic functions on the cylinder

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

It is known that the cylinder $X:=S^1\times \mathbb R$ is a complex manifold. Does $X$ have analytic functions. i.e, if $f:X\to \mathbb C$ is analytic then is $f$ necessarily constant?

Comment: It has a continuum of mutually non-isomorphic complex structures, e.g., annuli with varying ratios of inner radius to outer radius. All of these examples have many non-constant holomorphic functions. Is this not what you are asking about?

Comment: Can you explain your example to me please? Since I think this is what I am asking about. Is $X$ by the way Stein?

Comment: $X$ is $\Bbb C/\Bbb Z$. A function $f: X \to \Bbb C$ lifts to the universal cover $\tilde f: \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ with $\tilde f(z+1) = \tilde f(z)$, and conversely such a function descends to the quotient. So a holomorphic function $f: X \to \Bbb C$ is the same as a periodic holomorphic function on $\Bbb C$. You know many of these. $\sin(z/2\pi), \cos(z/2\pi), e^{z/2\pi}$.

Comment: Many smooth periodic functions ($\sum_n |a_nn^k| < \infty$ for every $k$) are not analytic. Iff $\sum_n |a_n|e^{ n y} < \infty$ for every $y\in (-r,R)$ then $\sum_n a_n e^{i n x}$ extends to an analytic function function $\sum_n a_n e^{i n z}, \Im(z) \in (-r,R)$ or $ \sum_n a_n z^n, |z|\in (e^{-R},e^r)$. Then for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}^*$, $\mathbb{C}/\lambda \mathbb{Z}$ is just a change of variable of $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}$, the two Riemann surfaces are isomorphic (in contrary to complex tori $\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}+i\mathbb{Z})$ non-isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}+2i\mathbb{Z})$)

Comment: Thanks Mike.  Do you know a good reference where one can learn more about those interesting facts.

Comment: Such regions are discussed in great detail in Ahlfors, if I recall correctly. (And as far as "Stein-ness" and so on go, these several complex variable notions that have content in several complex variables tend to degenerate in a single variable. E.g., it's easy to construct holomorphic functions with pretty random natural boundary sets.)